# Localhost default page on CentOS

Tags: nginx, centos

I install minimal version of CentOS 7 and Nginx. Nginx is started. But for the request 'localhost' in the browser is displayed "Welcome to CentOS" instead of "Welcome to NGINX". I want to display NGINX page.

Nginx config is default after installation. 
Directory /etc/httpd - does not exist.

Comment: What is the result of command: `netstat -anp|grep LISTEN|grep tcp`

Comment: tcp  0  0  127.0.0.1:25   0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN    1499/master                                    
tcp  0  0  0.0.0.0:80   0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN    3055/nginx

Comment: So its is nginx who listen on port 80. CHeck which config is in use of process ID  3055

Comment: Use the nginx.conf file without modification after installation. Nginx install just now.

Comment: Fragemt from config:  server { listen 80; root /usr/share/nginx/html; location / {}  }

Comment: Check what you have in this directory `/usr/share/nginx/html`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Despite all the install NGINX manuals in /usr/share/nginx/html there was the same html file whit same content as html file contents in /usr/share/nginx/html.